# "Object not found" error with XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I have been trying hard to get my xampp 1.8.3 to work but it has been no use.  I have already worked on it but I'm facing a problem in this new window installation on Win 7 64-bit
`http://localhost` is working for me and displaying phpmyadmin therein but `http://localhost/htdocs/file_name.php` is giving me an "Object not found!" error every time.

> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11

I have re-installed it 3 times already.

Comment: "htdocs" is normally the DOCUMENT_ROOT (that localhost refers to), so you would not normally specify this in the URL. I would expect the URL to be `http://localhost/file_name.php`. To be honest, if you are having to specify "htdocs" in the URL then the `DocumentRoot` (in your server config) is probably set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just added below lines in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf and restart apache

Alias /htdocs "C:/xampp/htdocs/"

   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to create another folder inside htdocs, you must have .php files in htdocs because is where your localhost direct. localhost/text.php